# Does viewing an SQS message in console increase receive count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am new to AWS. I have a dead-letter SQS with 5 messages and I inspected the messages a few times while I was trying to figure out how they landed in the dead-letter queue. I am using AWS console to inspect the messages: right click the SQS, then select "View/Delete Messages" and click "Start polling for messages". And every time I inspect I see a higher `ReceiveCount` for all 5 messages, typically incremented by 1. What I don't understand is whether that means some other component is reading messages from the SQS or whether my act of very inspecting itself is causing the `ReceiveCount` to increment. So my question is, is the latter even a possibility? Can viewing the message from console result in incrementing the `ReceiveCount`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. It is similar to  `NumberOfMessagesReceived` CloudWatch metric:

> The number of messages returned by calls to the ReceiveMessage action.

So each time you execute `View/Delete Messages` the messages are considered as received and no other consumer can view them until their visibility timeout finishes. Also you using `View/Delete Messages` contributes to general retry count a message in the queue. So if you have DLQ with default of 2 retries, and you view the messages twice, they will end up in the DLQ.

Comment: You'd imagine they'd add a way to not increment this value at all times or have another value that represents only the amount of times the message was actually being processed. I can't imagine someone manually processing messages from the console