# is it possible to know how many times sqs messsage has been read

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a use case to know how many times sqs message has been read in my code.

For example we read message from SQS, for abc reason/exception we cant process that message . Now the same message available in queue to read after visibility timeout.

This will create endless loop. Is there a way to know how many times particular sqs  message has been read and returned back to queue.

I am aware this can be handled via dead letter queue. Since that requires more effort I am checking is there any other option

i dont want to retry the message if it fails more than x time and i want to delete it. Is it possible in SQS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `ReceiveMessage()`, you can specify a list of `AttributeNames` that you would like returned.

One of these attributes is `ApproximateReceiveCount`, which returns "the number of times a message has been received across all queues but not deleted".

It is an 'approximate' count due to the highly parallel nature of SQS -- it is possible that the count is slightly off if a message was processed around the same time as this request.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do this manually by looking at the `approximateReceiveCount` attribute of your messages, [see this question on how to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901273/how-to-get-messages-receive-count-in-amazon-sqs-using-boto-library-in-python). You just need to implement the logic to read the count and decide whether to try processing the message or delete it. Note however that `receiveCount` is affected by more than just programmatically processing messages: [viewing messages in the console will increment it too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783523/does-viewing-an-sqs-message-in-console-increase-receive-count).

That being said **a DLQ is a premade solution for exactly this usecase**. It's not a lot of additional work: all you have to do is [create another SQS queue, set it as the DLQ of your processing queue, and set the number of retries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-dead-letter-queue.html). Then, the DLQ handles all your redrive logic, **and** instead of deleting messages after `n` failures they're moved to the DLQ, where you can manually look at them to understand why they're failing, set metrics alarms on the queue, and if you want manually re-drive the messages into your processing queue. Or just ignore them until they age out of the queue based on its retention policy - the important thing is that the DLQ gives you the **option** of being able to see which messages failed after the fact, while deleting them outright does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is not just deleting sqs message i need need to update required data base tables regarding this failures. So if i move to DLQ i need to trigger one lambda to perform this databse update Or i need to create a poller for DLQ . This is what i meant as more work